# How to get the cwd in c++ (Linux)

Tags: c++

How do I get the path of the current working directory in C++.

I know in python its looks this:

```
import os
path = os.getcwd()
```

I need something similar in C++ which I'm unable to find out.

Comment: If you do a search for e.g. `c++ getcwd` what results do you get then`?

Answer (score 0):

It's platform dependent. If you use some frameworks like Qt, they have own tools. Python uses POSIX functions and on POSIX-compatible platform they are accessible from C++, some are available in Windows under same names, but POSIX layer there doesn't support multibyte paths. `GetCurrentDirectory` is the name of Windows API function.

There is draft declared by standard: std::experimental::filesystem::current_path

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/current_path